# What is the best method to analyze multiple and matched linear numeric response?

Tags: generalized-linear-model

I have a survey with ten questions, and participants should answer each one reporting how frequent is his/her symptom on a scale from 0 to 10. These question are repeated twice considering "Now" and "Before the treatment".
I have grouped these 10 question in four "domains" and calculate, for each participant, the mean answer for each domain, either in the "NOW" section and in the "Before the treatment". I have several covariates (Age, type of treatment, educational attainment...) and I would like to see if there is any difference, for each of these four domains, before and after the treatment.

I would like to ask what is the best way to perform this kind of analysis? I was thinking of a linear model, but I would like to ask if other methods are more indicated in this case.

Thank you!

**New information**
I have all the data to all of ten questions before and after the treatment. For the research purpose, they can easily be grouped in four group.
I have a total of 62 patients, 25 assigned to "Treatment A" and 37 assigned to "Treatment B".

Comment: Welcome to cv, Lorenzo :-) So you have 10 questions, each with answers 0-10, right? One might critizise that you take the mean of ordinal data (0 to 10), but this is often tolerated when scales have many levels (I don't know if this was the reason for downvote?). Do you have all data (before, now, answers to all 10) or are some missing? How many participants, roughly?

Comment: @Ute Thank you very much for the kind reply! Yes I have 10 questions, each with answers 0-10 and have all the data before and after the treatment. For the research purpose, they can easily be grouped in four group. I have a total of 62 patients, 25 assigned to "Treatment A" and 37 assigned to "Treatment B". No idea why it was downvoted :D
I was thinking the best method to minimize the number of test. Another option ay be would be running multiple (non)parametrical test and correct with Bonferroni?

Comment: It depends a bit on your goals. I think if you treat the answers as numeric variables anyway, you can calculate the difference now - before, and then analyze that difference in a multivariate linear model (four dependent variables, for each question group) . Let's see, maybe some other users have further suggestions.